# Vuejs returns [object Object] from data attribute

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ess57qLn/) (check the console) and all you will see is `[object Object]` instead of `person` data:

So, basically I have a vuejs instance and a div for `v-for` to iterate an object

```
<div id='app'>
  <p v-for="person in people[0]"> 
    <span> {{ person.name }}</span>
        <i class="fa fa-check" 
        v-bind:data-identity="person" 
        @click="addDetail($event)"></i>
  </p>
</div>
```

The problem is that if I echo `{{ person }}` I can see a JSON data on the page, but if I try to get it in the function `addDetail()` with `e.target.dataset.identity` then all I get is `[object Object]` and not the json data. I have tried `JSON.parse` and `String` methods, non of them work.

Comment: would  @click="addDetail(person)" do the trick ?

Comment: does it show `[object Object]` when you try to log the object?

Comment: @Nemani yes, you can see the jsfiddle console I only get `[object Object]`

Comment: @hannesneukermans It does not matter how person is passed, I always get the `[object Object]` output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-bind:data-identity="person"` coverts person to string hence you can't attach an object to dataset
 as any object.toString() method returns `[Object object]` and you are getting the same

try to attach any string like person.name and see if it is reflected in your dataset

https://jsfiddle.net/qthg4Lwm/

hope this will help :)

EDIT: All data attributes are `string`
read  this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

**from above article**

> Each property is a string and can be read and written. In the above
>   case setting article.dataset.columns = 5 would change that attribute
>   to "5".

Comment: I don't know why your jsfiddle isn't working. Did you forget to update it? Because I still don't understand

Comment: Thanks. But you are still passing `person.name` if I have to do it your way, I would need many `data-` attributes. I just want to pass the whole `person` object in one data attr

Comment: As mentioned in my Answer, you can't pass object to data attribute, data attribute converts any passed value to `String`

Comment: instead you can pass person object to `addDetail` function

Answer (score 2):

Just passing handler method `@click` is enough. See Vue reference for [event handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers)

Template:

```
<i class="fa fa-check" @click="addDetail(person)"></i>
```

JS:

```
methods: {
  addDetail: function (person) {
    console.log(person);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's still the same, no difference from the output I was getting

Comment: I have edited my answer. By doing this you'll get the person object every time you click on `i` tag. Please check and let me know

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to access "person" through event and the DOM but give it as parameter to the function addDetail

Template

```
<div id='app'>
  <p v-for="person in people[0]"> 
    <span> {{ person.name }}</span>
        <i class="fa fa-check" 
        @click="addDetail(person)"></i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Script

```
...
methods: {
  addDetail: function(person){
    console.log(person)
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i have the same var name in html (inside v-for) & and in data function and everytime another var been used by browser...

Answer (score 0):

For me using `JSON.stringify()` solved that problem:

```
v-bind:data-identity="person"
```

will give `data-identity="[object object]"`

Where as:

```
v-bind:data-identity="JSON.stringify(person)"
```

will convert your json/object to string, and it will work

`data-identity="{"id":1,"name":"User 1"}"`